# Is it alright to add a disk size monitoring script for NAGIOS, using loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, disk-usage, monitoring, nagios

I have a process that gets sizes for all disks on server, writes it into a file like this

```
# cat disksize
DISK# ACTUAL WARNING CRITICAL
disk1 12     20      30
disk2 45     60      75
```

first row of file is for reference, showing what each column is for. Below is monitoring script, but I'm not sure if it will work for nagios, as some of these sizes may result in OK, some maybe in warning. Anyone give any insight on this, please

```
# cat check-disk_size

#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOGFILE='disksize'

cat ${LOGFILE} | while
  read disk_name actual warning critical
do
  if [ $actual -ge $warning ]; then
    echo "WARNING: $disk_name has reached standard warning limit, Current actual: ${actual}"
    exit 1
  elif [ $actual - ge $critical ]; then
    echo "WARNING: $disk_name has reached standard critical limit, Current actual: ${actual}"
    exit 2
  else
    echo "OK: $disk_name is under optical limit, Current actual: ${actual}"
    exit 0
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script (as written) will not do what you expect. The biggest problem is that you could `exit 0` prematurely from the loop, missing possible Critical disk entries that follow. Less dangerously, the script could `exit 1` with a Warning when Critical problems exist. Nagios will base the [status of this check on the exit code](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html), so your script could give confusing results simply based on the ordering of the entries in the file.

I would recommend restructuring the script so that it returns exactly what you expect, given the data in the file. Should it roll up the worst alert? Should it count how many alerts are in the file?  The safest idea would be to roll up the worst alert, so that every disk has to be below the Warning threshold in order for the Nagios alert to be "OK", but your environment may dictate other requirements.

Here's one possibility that rolls up the worst alert:

```bsh
awk '
BEGIN {
  warn=0
  crit=0
}

{
  if ($2 > $3) ++warn
  if ($2 > $4) ++crit
}
END {
  if (crit) {
        print "CRITICAL: one or more disks have reached the standard crtical limit"
        exit 2
  } else if (warn) {
        print "WARNING: one or more disks have reached the standard warning limit"
        exit 1
  } else {
        print "OK: all disks are under their limits"
        exit 0
  }
}
' < file
```

It's just an example to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, much appreciated. But is there a way to output which disk has exceeded this limit?

Comment: I mean, sure. But that's a separate question, and the idea behind a Nagios alert is that you alert an admin who then goes and fixes the problem(s). IMHO, if the same person can & should fix *all* of the disk problems, then they should only need one alert to the situation. If you need separate alerts for separate administrators, then you would write separate scripts and alerts based on that. My two cents!

Comment: (In other words, maybe the (one) admin who receives the alert goes and looks at the data file to see what's wrong, or runs `df`, etc)